# CRM FetchXML fetch more than 5000 records

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I have more than 5000 records that I want to fetch with this query, but I get cookie with null value every time. I realized that linked entity is the problem here, because when I remove it I get the cookie every time.

```
<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical" distinct="true" page="1" count="2000" >
    <entity name="listmember" >
        <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="entityid" alias="c" >
            <attribute name="contactid" />
            <attribute name="telephone1" />
            <link-entity name="phonecall" from="ic_customer" to="contactid" alias="pc" link-type="outer"  distinct="true">
                <attribute name="activityid" />
                <filter type="and" >
                    <filter type="or" >
                        <condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="1" />
                        <condition attribute="ic_end" operator="on-or-after" value="2016-11-12" />
                    </filter>
                </filter>
            </link-entity>
            <filter type="and" >
                <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
                <condition attribute="telephone1" operator="not-null" />
                <condition attribute="donotphone" operator="eq" value="0" />
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
        <filter type="and" >
            <condition attribute="listid" operator="in" >
                <value>
                    {f89087ef-7017-e611-80e3-5065f38a3951}
                </value>
            </condition>
            <condition entityname="pc" attribute="activityid" operator="null" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Anybody knows how to get paging cookie with this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this particular problem is that you need to specify ID column on your root entity. In this example you need to add `listmemberid` attribute to root `listmember` entity.

```
<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical" distinct="true" page="1" count="2000" >
    <entity name="listmember" >
        <attribute name="listmemberid" />
        <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="entityid" alias="c" >
            <attribute name="contactid" />
            <attribute name="telephone1" />
            <link-entity name="phonecall" from="ic_customer" to="contactid" alias="pc" link-type="outer"  distinct="true">
                <attribute name="activityid" />
                <filter type="and" >
                    <filter type="or" >
                        <condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="1" />
                        <condition attribute="ic_end" operator="on-or-after" value="2016-11-12" />
                    </filter>
                </filter>
            </link-entity>
            <filter type="and" >
                <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
                <condition attribute="telephone1" operator="not-null" />
                <condition attribute="donotphone" operator="eq" value="0" />
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
        <filter type="and" >
            <condition attribute="listid" operator="in" >
                <value>
                    {f89087ef-7017-e611-80e3-5065f38a3951}
                </value>
            </condition>
            <condition entityname="pc" attribute="activityid" operator="null" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your post reminded me that I've heard of this before, and sure enough I went to my notes and saw "Fetchxml with linkentity doesn't support paging".  However, I can't seem to find any official information about the limitation, which feels strange.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure it is the case that fetch queries with link entities don't support paging.  Try executing using a QueryExpression instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    IOrganizationService organizationservice;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();

        credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";

        credentials.UserName.Password = "password";


        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        organizationservice = new OrganizationServiceProxy(
            new Uri("_your org service_Organization.svc"), null, credentials, null);
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("account")
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "accountnumber" }),
            PageInfo = new PagingInfo()
            {
                Count = 250,
                PageNumber = 1,
                ReturnTotalRecordCount = false,
                PagingCookie = null
    }
        };

        EntityCollection results = null;

        while (true)
        {



            results = organizationservice.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            foreach (Entity record in results.Entities)
            {
                accountBuffer.AddRow();


                if (record.Contains("accountnumber"))
                    accountBuffer.accountnumber = record.GetAttributeValue<string>("accountnumber");


            }



            if (results.MoreRecords)
            {
                query.PageInfo.PageNumber++;
                query.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }




}
```